# Definition of a good question

Tags: discussion

### What does Stack Overflow consider as a Good Question?

These are some of the questions I have asked, after my account was reopened to ask questions. And I was very careful in asking them. But yet someone or the other downvotes it? I want to know the reason why? If there aren't appropriate reasons, I request removal of the downvotes.

These are the questions:

[How to include html tags when rendering the output in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540608/how-to-include-html-tags-when-rendering-the-output-in-the-browser)
[Determining the Time and Space complexity of a given code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579273/determining-the-time-and-space-complexity-of-a-given-code)

Comment: There's already a pretty good definition [here in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do you have any points arguing your questions don't fit with all of the points given there?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you've found about SO's quality guidelines, how you've tried to address problems with your earlier questions, and exactly how you think your newer questions follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 12):

People have the freedom to vote however they like. Your request to get votes revoked is a non-starter. The only exception would be if there are signs of vote abuse, like serial voting. But I see no indication of that happening here.

Feedback on your questions:

- The first one actually looks pretty good to me. I'm no HTML expert, though. Maybe they have seen similar questions too many times, or it seems too trivial to them. I think the title could be clearer, I only understood what you were looking for once I read the question. Maybe something like "Displaying literal HTML tags in browser output" would be clearer.
- The second question is kind of confusing. It partly sounds like you want explanations for the complexity concepts, and partly that you're looking for ways to optimize the provided code. The complexity questions are very basic computer science concepts that probably have been explained many times, and can be found in various sources (books, online, etc). This is not the ideal site to look for explanations of basic concepts. And questions should be focused and specific, not a mix of separate questions.

Disclaimer: In the interest of not feeding the meta effect, I have not voted on any of your SO questions.